# discord.js how to give adjustable leveled roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

hello guys im making a public bot, my bot is working on the level system. I can only give a server a special role according to the level`if(level = 5){ //addRole }` im using for that. So i made it a object like

```
rewards[message.guild.id] = [
{level: 1, reward: "rol1ID"},
{level: 2, reward: "rol2ID"}
]
```

my goal is for the server owners to make them adjustable (which I managed to set this as an object), but I don't know how to give the role of that level and delete the previous level role when members reach the specified level.can u guys help me thx

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This answer was written assuming you're using the latest discord.js, which is v12 at the time of writing. If you are using v11, please replace `roles.add()` and `roles.remove()` with `addRole()` and `removeRole()`

You're going to have to find a way to trigger a level up event and when doing so you could do the following for the roles:

```js
prevLvl = rewards[message.guild.id].find(reward => reward.level === USER_CURRENT_LEVEL - 1)
newLvl = rewards[message.guild.id].find(reward => reward.level === USER_CURRENT_LEVEL)

prevRoleID = prevLvl.find(data => data.reward)
newRoleID = newLvl.find(data => data.reward)

message.member.roles.remove(prevRoleID) // This will only work if levelling up is triggered by the user sending something in chat, otherwise, you need to get the `GuildMember` object of the user.
message.member.roles.add(newRoleID)
```